# Igraph R Community Detection

Tags: r, igraph

We are using igraph with R to detect communities with a large dataset of 7 million nodes and around 100 million edges.

We used several methods `(cluster_walktrap, cluster_edge_betweenness, cluster_fast_greedy)` and for every method, we have no result after 3-4 hours of processing. We are using a 64Gb memory server and during the process we still have free memory (not a memory problem), but no result at the end.

Do you have an idea what it might be?

Thank you

Comment: are you running the algorithms to completion or are you terminating them? [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/summary-of-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph-0-6/) lists the runtimes for all the community detection algorithms in `igraph`.

Comment: for edge-betweenness you calculate the shortest path between all node pairs. that's (7000000!) ≈ *inifite shortest path calculations.* that is not going to work. are you using a cutoff?